# Error on export_text for decision tree Sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, decision-tree

I'm trying to use the function `export_text` from sklearn.tree (version 1.0.2), but when I'm using the parameter feature_names I get an error, this is what I'm trying

```py
# decision_tree is the fitted algorithm
text_representation = export_text(decision_tree=decision_tree, feature_names=decision_tree.feature_names_in_)
```

[image]

If I call the function without the feature_names parameter it works, I already checked and the `decision_tree.feature_names_in_` returns the right names, the same I used as input for the algorithm

If I use this other similar function with the same arguments, it works fine

```py
plot_tree(decision_tree=decision_tree, feature_names=decision_tree.feature_names_in_)
```

any idea of what could it be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a small bug in the export_text code. Try forcing `features_names_in_` to be a python list.

```
# decision_tree is the fitted algorithm
text_representation = export_text(decision_tree=decision_tree, feature_names=decision_tree.feature_names_in_.tolist())
```

I assume you used a `pandas.DataFrame` when generating the DecisionTree so that you get the `feature_names_in_`?

If that's the case then `feature_names_in_` will be a `numpy.ndarray`.

The `export_text` code does a simple: `if feature_names:` test to check for features, but numpy will raise the error you see.

This looks like it's specific to the `export_text`, so you don't see it for `plot_tree`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! You're right, as features_names_in was a NumPy array it was falling, forcing it into a list worked, thanks again